# Can you tell me how can i add just first three places of an array in java no matter what the size of array is?

Tags: java, arrays

basically my question is how can I just add the first three places of an array of size 5 and access them. I have been trying, but I just can't get it.

There is an array of students and i want to remove some elements of the array and print the rest:

```
Students[] temp = new Students[(sArray.length-1)];
int j = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++){
  if (i != value ){
    temp[j] = sArray[i];
    j++;
  }

  sArray = temp;
  count = count-1;
}

for(int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++){
  // this will just print, but it is not printing, 
  // and count is the no of students.
  result+= sArray[i].toString()+"\n";
  result+="\n";
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Show what you've got so far.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have a array of size 5 and want to print the first 3 elements of it? (Please update your question, there is an edit link.)

Comment: Why are you keeping a variable "count" for the number of students when sArray.length already gives you the number of students??

Comment: @donnyton count is for how many user created students so far and if user enter 2 then i have to remove the 1 first element of the array and then print the rest of the array on the screen so can u tell me answer for this

Comment: We can't tell you any answer until you explain your program in detail with proper grammar.  Why do you have to remove the first element of the array if the user enters 2 students?  You never said anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you are asking, but my best guess is that you want to expand an array.  The only way to do this in Java is to create a new array; e.g.

```
    int[] small = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
    ...
    int[] big = Arrays.copyOf(small, 5);
    // The 'big' array will have 5 elements, and the first 3 will
    // be the elements of 'old'.
```

Note that you cannot change the size of an array in Java.  The length is an immutable property of the array.

Comment: i dont want to expand the array its like an interactive program in which i ask user to enter something and i will store it in the array so when the user say print i have to print what he enter no matter the size of the array whether  it is all full or just first three

Comment: @user615603: You should use an ArrayList, in that case, since it is expandable. If you have to use an array, you need a separate variable that keeps track of how many elements of the array you actually have used.

Comment: @user615603 - your English is too difficult to understand.  And even looking at your code, I cannot figure out what you are asking.  Sorry.  Perhaps you should find someone who speaks your native language to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that you want to print all the elements of an Array even if the Array is not full.  The proper class to do this is really an ArrayList, which will expand and contract to your needs as you fill it (thus, it is always "full" and scales as things are added).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

If you really insist on using an Array, you should have given us more info/code so we know exactly what you are trying to do.  Having some code is a lot better than trying to explain using vague terms.  Anyways, for an Array of Objects, you can do

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    if(myArray[i] != null)
    {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

And for ints, since they are initialized to 0, you check against 0:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    if(myArray[i] != 0)
    {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```